# Typescript: accessing an array element does not account for the possibility of undefined return values

Tags: typescript

The following passes the Typescript type checker (v2.9.1), but throws a `TypeError` at run time.

```
interface Item { id: string }
const list: Item[] = [{ id: 'a' }, { id: 'b' }];
const item = list[3]; // type: Item
const itemId = item.id; // type: string
```

Given that accessing an element in a typed array could always return `undefined`, shouldn't item be `item: Item | undefined`, which would force you to do a null check?

Even more surprisingly to me, the following also type checks:

```
const item2: Item | undefined = list[3];
const item2Id = item2.id;
```

though casting the returned value does successfully fail the type check:

```
const item3 = list[3] as Item | undefined;
const item3Id = item3.id; // [ts] Object is possibly 'undefined'.
```

Creating an explicitly typed accessor function also catches the undefined case, but adds unnecessary overhead:

```
const getItem1 = (index: number, items: Item[]): Item | undefined => items[index];
const item3 = getItem1(3, list);
const item3Id = item3 && item3.id;
```

Is this a known limitation of typescript?  Are there recommended patterns or libraries for handling this case?

Comment: Here you go: https://github.com/danielnixon/eslint-plugin-total-functions

Comment: Instead of doing `list[3]`, I sometimes do `list.find((_, i) => i === 3)` because the nature of the `find` function will automatically give the potential `undefined` type.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

#### UPDATE for TS 4.1:

TypeScript 4.1 introduced a [`--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` compiler flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#checked-indexed-accesses---nouncheckedindexedaccess) that implements the suggestion in [microsoft/TypeScript#13778](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13778) to account for `undefined` in this way.  Note that the feature will not be enabled as part of the `--strict` set of compiler options and is being called "pedantic index signatures" because it will end up complaining about the possibility of `undefined` in situations where programmers might not expect or desire it.

---

#### PRE-TS4.1 ANSWER:

You have discovered that index signatures don't add `| undefined` to the element type the way that optional properties do.  It has been suggested at [microsoft/TypeScript#13778](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13778) to create a compiler option that would do this.  You can read the comments in that suggestion; they link to other issues, but the consensus is that the high false positive rate would make it nearly useless.

It is also mentioned that you have the ability to manually add `| undefined` to the element type:

```
const list: (Item | undefined)[] = [{ id: 'a' }, { id: 'b' }];
```

which will behave as you expect, without affecting the whole language.

Comment: Ah OK.  `(Item | undefined)[]` seems like a good way forward, though array methods like map will have to explicitly mark the project function's item argument as not undefined: `list.map((item) => item!.id);`

Comment: I've been using this approach: https://github.com/danielnixon/total-functions/

Comment: The `Array<Item | undefined>` syntax is preferred in this case

Comment: FYI it's `"noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,` in the `tsconfig.json`

Answer (score 3):

This is the intentional behavior. [See this issue on the TypeScript GitHub repo for a long discussion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13778)

> Even more surprisingly to me, the following also type checks:

You have `strictNullChecks` off; try turning it on.

Comment: hmm, I do have `strictNullChecks` on: `const item: Item = undefined` does not type check.  Any other reason this would be expected behavior?

Comment: @JamesConkling It's because the compiler "knowns" `list[3]` is not undefined, so it narrows the type of `item2` as soon as you assign it. It's the same if you do `const item2: Item | undefined = { id: "a"}`. Depending on your IDE, if you hover over `item2` on the first line it will say the type is `Item | undefined`, if you hover over item2 on the next line, it'll say the type is `Item`.