# Type check array.filter

Tags: javascript, typescript

Given the following code:

```
const nums = [1, 2, 3]
const filtered = nums.filter(n => n === 4)

filtered[100].toString()
```

Why isn't TypeScript complaining that `.toString()` wouldn't work because `filtered[100]` might be undefined?

Playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBGCuBbCMC8MDaBGANDATHgMwC6AUKJLAGYCWANlAKYBOTAJmnEhAHR2NWACjBoAfHDSp0AFgCUZMgOZt22AAzqSvKCADKUFrTABzIXKA

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with `filter()`; you can change it to [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBerzw) and the problem persists.  Maybe you want to [edit] the question to something like "why does TypeScript let you index into arrays without handling `undefined`?"

Comment: I closed this as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50647399/typescript-accessing-an-array-element-does-not-account-for-the-possibility-of-u); if that doesn't answer it for you then let me know and maybe we can reopen it.  Good luck!