# What is a generic type parameter T in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, generics

Going through the TS handbook.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html

> In TypeScript, generics are used when we want to describe a
> correspondence between two values. We do this by declaring a type
> parameter in the function signature:

```
function firstElement<Type>(arr: Type[]): Type | undefined {
  return arr[0];
}
```

> By adding a type parameter Type to this function and using it in two
> places, we’ve created a link between the input of the function (the
> array) and the output (the return value). Now when we call it, a more
> specific type comes out:

In this case is `Type` a keyword? When I see just `T` is that the same thing?

Am I understanding this section correctly? By adding  we are telling Typescript to assign whatever type the input is to the output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In this case is `Type` a keyword?

In your example, `Type` is a [generic type parameter (type variable)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#working-with-generic-type-variables).

> When I see just `T` is that the same thing?

Assuming the token is in the same position, yes.

> By adding we are telling Typescript to assign whatever type the input is to the output?

It's helpful for me to think about them analogous to parameters in functions, but for types. You're effectively telling typescript this:

"I'm creating a type parameter (variable) called `Type`. I'm going to accept an argument in this function which will be an array, and you should use the type of each element in the array as the real type in place of `Type`. I'm going to return one of the array elements, so the return type of this function should be the same type as one of the array elements (or `undefined` if I use an index at which there's no value)."

> Now, there's one more potentially confusing part to this, based on the example that you provided, which is "Why doesn't TypeScript account for the possibility of undefined when indexing an array element using square brackets?", and that's covered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50647536/438273).

Here's a concrete example:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=19&ssc=36&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMGAnAzlAogGwKYC2eYUAPACoCeADngHwAUAhqqgFyJW0DaAugJQcueRAB9E4ACZ4UYPJMQBvALAAoRIlR4oIVEhapuABl4BuNQF81agPQ3OACxjpEUGiOccwIAgCM8hrxqEAiYiAYAjIgAvIjcEQA0iABMSQDMZtaqdogA6g7EiADmMABuMGBFiAAGkdXhLlAF4ahFPsRQrnA1KBjY+EQk1Qm29tXC9QDuMDg4iP4hRDXefgH1C0wg6CJ4TBAOiHgDHYgVNXWjpy7VK-6o1QB0iADK3U0iWuggOJ3Ts-N4Lw+O5iCRgaSyeTBUKdT7fKBRWK9TC4QgdZisCL8cyqS7kJyNdxXDiYVAVIp8aFgMIGZIxOIAcgKszgDKSDMmcFQOEkDMyuOy9nyhRK5Uq51YyXqTEazRYbUGnSg3WqyP6aKGI0FNQmiD+cwWcCW1VJ5PWeAgm22hz2ByOGs6Z1qkuql2cNVNlUeLzezThPz1MwNgMQnqq4ikMgqUNUIWpsLwXx+dKRaBRxxIGNQyWxQA)

```ts
function firstElement<Type>(arr: Type[]): Type | undefined {
  return arr[0];
}

// This type is: number[]
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3];

// When giving `arr1` as the argument to `firstElement`,
// `Type` will become `number` because each element in `arr1`
// is `number`. So the result will be: number | undefined
const result1 = firstElement(arr1);

// This type is: string[]
const arr2 = ['hello', 'world'];

// When giving `arr2` as the argument to `firstElement`,
// `Type` will become `string` because each element in `arr2`
// is `string`. So the result will be: string | undefined
const result2 = firstElement(arr2);
```

Here's another example using `T` instead of `Type` for the generic type parameter:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwDbILbLFAglASTABNkAPAHgBUA+ACgEMAnJgLkSoG0BdAGkRgly7MCAwAjZEwCU7KogA+icKWCDkxRAG8AsAChEiJsiggmSZk06DSZbgG59AX336ICAM5RElxAF5ETgByAC8pOCD+IIRkSMQgqAB3CIdXPXcwL0Qwpjh-FHQsHHwiW0YWfgAGaXtEAHo6xC8mQQBzRWUhNTANN084dAA6VDhWuhy4GvrGgCIJmbSMrKgAC2NkfLRMbDxCITJypn4AZimGpqgWsHalFWRu3vT+oZGx1fXpac7VdWJ9IA)

```ts
function elementAtIndex<T>(arr: T[], index: number): T | undefined {
  return arr[index];
}

const arr = ['zero', 'one', 'two'];

const zero = elementAtIndex(arr, 0); // string | undefined
console.log(zero); // "zero"

const three = elementAtIndex(arr, 3); // string | undefined
console.log(three) // undefined
```

> FWIW, `elementAtIndex` in the example above is just a functional version of [`Array.prototype.at()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at), which should be in an upcoming release of TypeScript (probably `v4.6`).

Answer (score 2):

No, here `Type` is a plain identifier, which identifies a *type parameter*. Normally type parameters are named with capital case letters, like `T`, but more descriptive names are useful.

This declaration says:

```js
function firstElement   // We are defining a function
         <Type>         // The function has a type parameter
         (arr: Type[]): // and regular parameters of that type.
         Type | undefined // It returns either a value of the type
                          // given by the type parameter, or undefined.
```

The idea is that you may pass an array of elements of a particular type, and expect an element of that same type, statically checked:

`firsElement<number>([1,2,3])` will return a `number`, and the compiler will guarantee that it won't be a string or an object.

`firstElement<number>(['a', 'b'])` won't even compile, because it is asking for an array of numbers (by `<number>`), but receives an array of strings.

`firstElement<number>([])` will return `undefined`, because there is no first element to return. This is allowed by the `| undefined` clause in the return type.