# Why does typescript not require `undefined` when using the ?: operator on an array?

Tags: typescript

```
type Artifact = {
    a:string
}

const items : Artifact[] = [];

// this is a syntax error
let z?: Artifact;

// this is an error because you cannot assign undefined.
const b : Artifact = undefined;

// this worked!? but I don't think it should because the 
// value could be undefined
const c : Artifact = items?.[0];

// These work as expected.
const a : Artifact|undefined = undefined;
const d : Artifact|undefined = items?.[0];
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM+AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL+gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCbvCwDKgU8JkY7p7ehCTkVDQS2E6gnPCxGcwmZqDSTgzxxWWVoASMFmgYkAAeRJTInN3ymj4d-jSCeNsMq-wuoPaOltigAKoASgAywhK7SbGQZIIz5VWCFzSeCrZagNYbChbHaxUDcCjJZLfSDbExIAgUdxkUBIursJzCFJtXydajBBCcQQ0MwAUVWDEQC0gADVHBQGNJ3KAALygABEAAkYNAMOB4GRonzFBTBPB3AERcwABS0+mM9ysygc9wASmCKhwzQ8ZC8iHFzmB7BoXzcZmY7AYzEg-Fg0HUiQ58D0Ii8fLpDKZgj5SWxfPADlQAHJhAA5SASPlBFQAeS+ZHegmdWkgR1QjgUrmkeFATjNOmGWH0KAQiGhwkuNok4uiIgMHGxCyYrA4PCCqHalTI9WSDFgNF5AG9FCUSgx8lTKJxmIoAL7kxpUtKQRDCfKD4ej1AAbQAujzQKeANzBdw0ABeAH49xUhwjD9eZTRpKBn6+R2Pzy4bhIGSDJIG4D8NxoWAf33N8AN5eRt0EB8AiPAAGE9r2lKDjF-A8xwAHyAkCwNcXkSNAzhwMgykaFcfD4NQYieFI6jyK3HdUIwrDFCAA)

Comment: What is the `?:` operator?  Is your question "why does the compiler think an array read will never produce `undefined`?  I assume so; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50647399/2887218) and its answer.  If my assumption is wrong and you're asking something else, please [edit] to distinguish this from the other question. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Items are constantly defined in your code so "?" is ignored

I extended your example to show all variants [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4&noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true#code/FAFwngDgpgBAggJxASwGYEMDGIYF4YDewMJM6AXAM4gLIB2A5sAL7BtsA2UOAXgPzl4SNFhABuYJgD2dajABGMQYhQZseGAFc6AEyip6UHRPbTZOZCCgBbSsuFqQAbQC6MAD5bd+wzo2uJMzltPQM6IwBJK1t7VVFXDy9Q3w0Qn3DjYFRtbGQZGAZuKJtKAAoASliRbATPNLCjQmJSBG5NBDoYAJZJGTlMAAYlITj1fEsSpwGXQL6cTABGYZVqnHHoyj4AOimZ3vMYTAAmZYdRVO8GnWLbbd2JAHoH0hgAPRgAFUhYAHJ63x+MGQlBgdCkOHQlEoyAYdHQ8i4MBAUiR3xgPxWjh++36AGZTqM1gUihsKvdgE8XlTqVT3gB5eQAKyg6mBMAgUihyARYHR-wyPy2OPmABYCasNIUQDcyuU7tNHs9SO8vtB0ZjznVLgCgSCwRCubD4Yjkai1RizthscKyOLHO5+Y18I7MkEcH4qvaXRoJrcdgrgEA)

```
const items: Artifact[] | undefined = [];
const undefinedItems: Artifact[] | undefined = undefined;
function getItems(): Artifact[] | undefined {
    return [];
}
const c0 : Artifact = items[0];
const c1 : Artifact = items?.[0];
const c2 : Artifact = undefinedItems?.[0];
//    ^ Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Artifact'
const c3 : Artifact = getItems()[0];
//                    ^ Object is possibly 'undefined'.
const c4 : Artifact = getItems()?.[0];
//    ^ Type 'Artifact | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Artifact'
```