# Explicitly stating that the returned value from array index operator can be undefined is ignored by typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, nullable

I wanted to ask this as a comment to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50647536/2082874, but was not allowed due to lack of karma, so here goes.

I got bit by typescript not typing the return value of array index operator as possibly being undefined, and wanted to use the work around mentioned in the answer above, with explicitly specifying the returned value as possibly being undefined.

However as this example shows, it seems like typescript ignores the undefined part of the type later when using the value [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwE6oBQEoBciDeiAznkVKjGAOaIC+A2gLoEBQiiECZiqiAvIgCyyKAAsAdKmRgAJnAC22ANxtEMYIgy8AfIgAM4gKxZW7dqgCmUEKiRMV7WqsvXbieoRKIABmBDyAIwteAHdkIkQAEnxUWm86RhUnFk4wbiIAQXRSckoaAB9EcBkLYEoLGX4UdGx6PUYAfnEiFVTuTnkABzgiCqzUPE8cimo6RELi0vLKgXxVAHp5xAB1UQBPNQjM9GIQGRKwABsNtpgSy0qyEZppSrA4KCLZKbAK8eJc0dFgi0QG1S821QABoWLRWlw4IcLOJDnAqBgOt1ejJ+lgVEA)

```js
function arr(): { s: string }[] {
  const r = Math.random();
  if (r > 0.5) {
    return [];
  }
  return [{ s: `number was ${r}` }];
}

const sArr: string | undefined = arr()[0]?.s;
const composedArr: { s: string } | undefined = {
  // Why is sArr suddenly considered string and not undefined | string here ?
  s: sArr,
};
console.log(composedArr);
```

What gives? Why does typescript do that? Am I missing something here?

Comment: `sArr` is `string | undefined` but the property `s` is `string` because you explicitly typed it as such, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Are you looking for [`noUncheckedIndexedAccess`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess)?  https://tsplay.dev/WkldPw

Comment: @Behemoth s is indeed typed as string, but if you take my example and switches the index operator ([0]) to `.at(0)` you will see that `s: sArr,` yields a typescript type error because sArr may be undefined. But I am already specifying the type manually to possibly be undefined (as is suggested as a workaround in my SO link at the top) - so why does TS "overrule" my manual type specification? Because it deduces that index operator always returns not undefined, but still, it overrules my manually specified type, which I didn't know it does, if that is what happens

Comment: @VLAZ that could be a solution, but would affect our whole codebase, which might not be practical. What I am really looking for is an explanation for why typescript decides that my manual type specification (string | undefined) suddenly doesn't matter when I try to assign to the s property of composedArr.