# Typescript null check when using non-safe access of types with indes signature

Tags: typescript

Why is this not yielding that `test` might be potentially `undefined` while I've enabled `strictNullCheck` in the tsconfig.json.

(I don't know keys ahead of time)

```
const a: Record<string,{value: string}> = {}

a["test"].value
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgLhgJQKagE4BMA80MCWYA5gDQDeAbnADYCuqS+RxAvgHwwC8M5AUH1YC4AbQBEUVNDEBdAHTV6qIA)

Comment: `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` - [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgLhgJQKagE4BMA80MCWYA5gDQDeAbnADYCuqS+RxAvgHwwC8M5AUH1YC4AbQBEUVNDEBdAHTV6qIA)

Comment: Also related (same compiler option but used with arrays): [Typescript: accessing an array element does not account for the possibility of undefined return values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50647399)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`noUncheckedIndexedAccess` did the trick, though it was included with `strict` thanks boys

Comment: It's *not* included in `strict`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50647536), [the feature announcement](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#checked-indexed-accesses---nouncheckedindexedaccess), [the PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39560).